# I can't open my scripts using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, cryengine

When I am trying to open my script in CryEngine Window I face this warning in Visual Studio 2017
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCQOT.png)

[image]

How to fix?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/m12BS6Z.png - screenshot

Comment: Are you sure that you have C# support installed?

Comment: @3Dave yes, C# support is installed